# Kafka stream joins performance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have build a kafka streams application that is suppose to enrich real-time events with customer information among others.
The producer is capable of writing between 200k to over 500k messages per second based on load which is good. the expected average number of records per day is about 20-22 billion records for this given stream. kafka stream enrichment with joins become too slow only achieving about 40-50k events per second. Since I'm using selectkey it causes repartioning
and I have several other joins that I have to make. producer writes data in avro format. when I perform transformations without joins I'm able
to match with the producer. Below are code snippets of the joins I'm using:

message event have the following fields among others:
*customerid,deviceid,httpresponse,datetime,response-rate, sessionid*

```
//get device information
        final GlobalKTable<String,GenericRecord> device_info = builder.globalTable("device"); // contain about 250k records

//get customer information
         final GlobalKTable<String,GenericRecord> cust= builder.table("CustomerInfo"); // contain about 40 million customer records


// customer events
        KStream<String, GenericRecord>  eventstream= builder.stream("CustomerEvents"); //about 250k events per second



     eventstream.selectKey((key, value)-> value.get("customerid")))
                .leftJoin(cust, (dataKey,dataValue) -> dataKey, (data, customerinfo) -> {
        
        if(customerinfo!=null){

        data.put("customerName", customerinfo.get("customername"));
        //some other logic here

        }else{
        data.put("customerName", customerinfo.get("unknown"));
        // some logic here
            }
        return data;
        })
        .selectKey((key,value)-> value.get("deviceid").substring(0,8))
                .leftJoin(device_info, (dataKey,dataValue) -> dataKey, (data, deviceinfo) -> {


                    if(deviceinfo!=null) {

                        data.put("device_manufacturer", deviceinfo.get("manufacturer"));
                       
                    } else {
                        data.put("device_manufacturer", "unknown");
                    }
                    return  data;
                })
        .to("outputTopic", Produced.with(stringSerde, new JsonSerde<>(DataTransform.class)));
```

***Few things I have noticed:***

1. introduction of joins make data distribution across partitions to be skewed not sure how to fix that since the key determines where a messages is placed e.g. assume most of the data contain similar deviceids
2. selectkey causes repartioning meaning my data will have to do several round trips between the brokers and kafka stream application running on a different server

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking about what the behavior is, how to better distribute the keys, or how to improve performance?

Comment: Hi @wcarlson, I'm looking at how to improve performance.

Comment: If you fix your partitioning problem with join you would see performance improvements.  You might need to make a custom partitioner you can see more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933342/14165805

Comment: Thanks @wcarlson, Seems like I have some reading to do on how best to use a custom partitioner for even distribution of data. Would you have an idea how to go about joins without causing a repartition especially if you have multiple joins to make like in my case.

Comment: Repartitions are enforced where ever the is a key changing operation by default. There may be a way to optimize and not repartition but I am not familiar with it. If you can I would suggest joining streams in a logarithmic way, that might help reduce the number of repartitions a record has to go through end to end.